# Digital Certificate (Signature) Verification in Software Installation

Tags: security, encryption, certificate, digital-signature

I need to know what exactly happens during digital certificate (signature) verification when a software is installed by the operating system. I understand that this is a asymmetric key process and I have working knowledge of private key/public encryption process.

I have done some searching over the Internet and found some documents but can not seem to get the answer on the following questions (may be some of these are not that intelligent).

- When a software is being installed, who (on behalf of OS) gets the public key (digital signature) from the software publisher? Who is contacted here? Is there a daemon at the other end? Or there is a repository?
- What if I am not connected to the Internet? How will the verification process go over in this case?
- What if a software is falsely signed using the name of a reputed software company and I try to install it, which CA (Certificate Authority) will be contacted to protect me? Is the process automatic or I (installer) need to carry out some manual process?
- Is the public key of a software vendor stored locally after an installation? Where? Can I view these?
- Does my browser play any role in the software signature verification process? Or the browser is concerned about the `https` sites only?

Please make your answers generic (independent of OS). If you need to mention some specific software, my order of preferences are those in Ubuntu and Windows, in that sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends greatly on the operating system, so there is no generic answer possible.

**In Arch Linux**, packages are signed using PGP  – not by the original author (who provides only the source code), but by the *packager* (who compiles the source code into a program and creates the signed package).

The signatures are kept in the package database, along with the rest of package information. (For third-party packages – when you download just the `.pkg.tar.xz` file – the signature will be in a second `.pkg.tar.xz.sig` file.) The database itself can be signed, but usually isn't.

`pacman` in Arch Linux verifies signatures against the keys in `/etc/pacman/gnupg.d` (managed using `pacman-key`); if you don't have the signer's key yet, it will ask to download the key from a [keyserver](http://www.rossde.com/PGP/pgp_keyserv.html). There are no central "certificate authorities" – PGP uses a Web of Trust algorithm, and the validity of someone's key depends on what other people signed that key. (For example, all official developers' keys are signed by five "master keys", and the master keys are marked as "trusted", therefore all developers' keys are also trusted by the package manager. These keys come by default on all Arch systems, in the `archlinux-keyring` package.)

In PGP, since there are no CAs, a key can be revoked only by its owner. To find out about new signatures or revocations, you have to periodically update the cached keys from a keyserver; `gpg --refresh-keys` does this for your own keyring, while `pacman-key --refresh-keys` updates the keyring used for verifying packages.

**In Ubuntu**, PGP is also used, but somewhat differently. Packages themselves are almost never signed, they're verified only against the hashsums in the package database, which is signed by an automated process (using a key named "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key" or "Launchpad PPA for John Smith" or similar).

The signatures are verified against a local keyring too (`/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`, maintained using `apt-key`) – but differently from Arch, the Ubuntu package manager ignores key signatures and trusts *all* keys in that keyring, therefore it never downloads keys automatically, and never needs to refresh them. Official keys come preinstalled in various `foo-keyring` packages (`debian-keyring` and similar), and if one of those keys is revoked, the updated package removes it.

**On Windows**, programs can be signed using "Authenticode", which is basically X.509 used for code-signing. The signature, as well as the signer's own certificate, is embedded inside the program's `.exe` file. *(The certificate has to be attached because unlike PGP, X.509 does not have keyservers, despite the original plans X.500 once had.)* Differently from Linux, most Windows programs are distributed in compiled form by their authors, so the .exe file is signed by the author directly.

The publisher's certificate is verified against a local database of trusted Certificate Authorities. On Windows, you can see it in `certmgr.msc` – the included certificates are decided upon by Microsoft according to requests from CAs. (Note: Supposedly, Windows 7 is able to download the needed CA certificates when needed, so the list in Certificate Manager might be incomplete.)

While verifying the signature, Windows will contact the issuer's OCSP server to check if the certificate hasn't been revoked yet. (The OCSP server address is usually part of the publisher's certificate.) In other words, revocations are handled by the same CA which issued the certificate in the first place. (Note: I'm not sure if OCSP checking is on by default. There is an option to enable/disable it in *Control Panel → Internet → Advanced → Security*.) In some cases, Microsoft will also mark known-fake certificates as "untrusted" and distribute them the same way as regular updates to the CA list. In `certmgr.msc` you can see several certificates having been revoked this way.

Some browsers (such as Opera or Firefox) have their own databases of CA certificates. Those are not used by Windows. Meanwhile, Internet Explorer and Google Chrome use the same Windows database.